Angular material table css
Have ngx-admin template project, Angular 15 and angular material table.
Tried to apply CSS like this but no luck:
.mat-footer-row,
.mat-header-row {
  //border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  height: 15px !important;
  background-color: #27315a;
  color: #fff;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(odd) .mat-cell {
  background-color: nb-theme(background-basic-color-1);
  font-weight: normal;
  color: nb-theme(text-basic-color);
}

.mat-row:nth-child(even) .mat-cell {
  background-color: nb-theme(background-basic-color-2);
  //background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: nb-theme(text-basic-color);
  font-weight: normal;
}

Then tried this snippet and style applied:
td[mat-cell] {
  padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffa600;
}

Can someone explain why this happen?
Thanks!

The td[mat-cell] selector is more specific than .mat-footer-row, .mat-header-row and .mat-row .mat-cell. The browser gives higher priority to more specific selectors, which is why the styles in the second snippet are applied while the styles in the first snippet are not.

Something like 'sudo' for CSS :) . Thanks!
